# Adding product thumbnail to Woocommerce view-order page issue

Tags: woocommerce, thumbnails

I have been using this code sucessfully for nearly 2 years, however I'm wondering if the latest Woocommerce updates have changed it somewhat as I now get a warning error in the log regarding this line `$thumbnail = $product->get_image(array( 60, 120));`

Is it possible this needs updating, and if so, what to? Any help would be much appreciated

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_item_name', 'display_product_image_in_order_item', 20, 3 );
function display_product_image_in_order_item( $item_name, $item, $is_visible ) {
    // Targeting view order pages only
    if( is_wc_endpoint_url( 'view-order' ) ) {
        $product   = $item->get_product();
        $thumbnail = $product->get_image(array( 60, 120));
        if( $product->get_image_id() > 0 )
            $item_name = '<div class="item-thumbnail">' . $thumbnail . '</div>' . $item_name;
    }
    return $item_name;
}
```

Comment: The code still works perfectly on last WooCommerce version 4.3.0 … So the problem in your case is may be related to: WooCommerce overridden templates via your theme that are not up to date, or some other custom code, or something else in your theme or a third party plugin…

Comment: Thanks for the info @LoicTheAztec - I'll investigate those other things